# How to prevent this Exception: Value does not fall within the expected range. with WaitHandle.WaitAny method?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, waithandle

> Exception at QueueCompareProcessThread() Message:Value does not fall
>   within the expected range. Trace:   at
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitMultiple(WaitHandle[] waitHandles,
>   Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext, Boolean WaitAll)    at
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(WaitHandle[] waitHandles, Int32
>   millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)    at
>   System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(WaitHandle[] waitHandles)

I get the exception above when I use the `WaitAny` method on a `WaitHandle` in a thread. Please help me to sort out the issue. Here is my part of the code:

```
public void QueueCompareProcessThread(QueueProcesses Qp)
{
    try
    {
        WaitHandle[] pHandles = Qp.GetRunningProcessesHandles();
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(pHandles);
        Qp.RemoveExitedProcess();   // clearing the process list 
        // strange behavior is while clearing the process list i'm getting the exception in the thread Waitany method
        // Does Waitany method still working after it returns?
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        utils.Log("QProc Exception at QueueCompareProcessThread() Message:" + e.Message + " Trace:" + e.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please give some idea about the WaitAny method and help me to sort out the issue?

Comment: It helps a lot if you log `ex.ToString()` instead of only logging the message and the stacktrace. Currently you are missing the exception type in you log. If you know the exception type you can look up in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z(v=vs.110).aspx) what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the `pHandles` array actually contains elements and that each element is only contained once. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z(v=vs.110).aspx) states that an `ArgumentException` is thrown if *“`waitHandles` is an array with no elements, and the .NET Framework version is 2.0 or later”*.

```
if (pHandles.Any())
{
    WaitHandle.WaitAny(pHandles);
}
```